# Side-By-Side Images - MATLAB Report Generator

Tags: matlab, pdf

Based on the matlab documentation example (https://www.mathworks.com/help/rptgen/ug/side-by-side-images.html) I was trying to repeat it with other two images.

Code:

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;
 
import mlreportgen.report.*
import mlreportgen.dom.*
  
linkImage = image(imread('https://www.aviationmegastore.com/img/prod/full/f/9/167408_0.jpg'));
RGBImage = image(imread('sevilla.jpg'));
rpt = Report('PDFreport', 'pdf');
 
imgStyle = {ScaleToFit(true)};
RGBImage.Style = imgStyle;
linkImage.Style = imgStyle;
 
lot = Table({RGBImage, ' ', linkImage});
 
lot.entry(1,1).Style = {Width('3.2in'), Height('3in')};
lot.entry(1,2).Style = {Width('.2in'), Height('3in')};
lot.entry(1,3).Style = {Width('3.2in'), Height('3in')};
 
lot.Style = {ResizeToFitContents(false), Width('100%')};
 
add(rpt, lot);
close(rpt);
rptview(rpt);
```

but I get this error:

```
Unrecognized property 'Style' for class 'matlab.graphics.primitive.Image'.

Error in Untitled (line 13)
RGBImage.Style = imgStyle;
```

How do I fix it and what causing it?

Comment: Did you try using `img1 = Image(which('ngc6543a.jpg')); img1.Style = imgStyle;`, just as in the example? Why are you using `image(imread())`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`image` and `Image` are not the same thing.  When you do:

```
import mlreportgen.report.*
import mlreportgen.dom.*
```

You are bringing in different components that include the properties you are after.  Using `image` returns a `matlab.graphics.primitive.Image`.  If you use `Image` you will get a `mlreportgen.dom.Image` which has `Style`.

A quick test shows that the included `sevilla.jpg` loaded fine but I did need to save a local copy of `167408_0.jpg` in order for `Image` to process it.  So the correct commands after copying the file to the working directory are:

```
RGBImage = Image(which('sevilla.jpg'));
linkImage = Image('167408_0.jpg');
```

Comment: Further to this, it might be advisable to _not_ use `import` at all, and use `mlreportgen.dom.Image()` instead of `Image()`, since it makes it more obvious which function is being called; `import` pollutes the namespace. I assume MathWorks have chosen to do this to make their code look "cleaner", but in reality it causes headaches like the OP is facing