# Report with side by side two images and a splited table - Matlab

Tags: matlab, pdf, report

I am trying in the code below to generate a report with side by side two images and a splited table but I get an error. Why this error occur?

Code:

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;

import mlreportgen.report.*
import mlreportgen.dom.*
import mlreportgen.utils.*

Name = {'A';'B';'C';'D';'E';'A';'B';'C';'D';'E'};
codeA = [8;3;8;0;4;8;3;8;0;4];
Height = [1;8;4;7;8;8;3;1;0;4];
Weight = [6;2;1;4;5;8;3;1;1;4];
T = table(Name,codeA,Height,Weight,codeA,Height,Weight,codeA,Height,Weight);

Image1 = Image(which('coins.png'));
Image2 = Image(which('sevilla.jpg'));

rpt = Report("myPDF","pdf");
  
imgStyle = {ScaleToFit(true)};
Image2.Style = imgStyle;
Image1.Style = imgStyle;

lot = Table({Image2, ' ', Image1});

lot.entry(1,1).Style = {Width('3.2in'), Height('3in')};
lot.entry(1,2).Style = {Width('.2in'), Height('3in')};
lot.entry(1,3).Style = {Width('3.2in'), Height('3in')};
lot.Style = {ResizeToFitContents(false), Width('100%')};
add(rpt, lot);
 
chapter = Chapter("Title",'Table Report');
table = FormalTable(T);
table.Border = 'Solid';
table.RowSep = 'Solid';
table.ColSep = 'Solid';

para = Paragraph(['The table is sliced into two tables, '...
    'with the first column repeating in each table.']);
para.Style = {OuterMargin('0in','0in','0in','12pt')};
para.FontSize = '14pt';
add(chapter,para)

slicer = TableSlicer("Table",table,"MaxCols",5,"RepeatCols",1);
totcols = slicer.MaxCols - slicer.RepeatCols;
slices = slicer.slice();
for slice=slices
    str = sprintf('%d repeating column and up to %d more columns',...
        slicer.RepeatCols,totcols);
    para = Paragraph(str);
    para.Bold = true;
    add(chapter,para)
    add(chapter,slice.Table)
end

add(rpt,chapter)
close(rpt)
rptview(rpt)
```

Error:

*Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 10.

Error in try1 (line 26)

lot.entry(1,1).Style = {Width('3.2in'), Height('3in')};*

Comment: True and done :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the variable

```
Height = [1;8;4;7;8;8;3;1;0;4];
```

Then you try and use the report gen function `Height`

```
lot.entry(1,1).Style = {Width('3.2in'), Height('3in')};
```

Because you've shadowed the `Height` function with a variable, MATLAB is trying to get the element of this array at index `'3in'`, which is either nonsensical or (via some implicit ASCII conversion) is way out of range.

Per my [comment on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70852194/side-by-side-images-matlab-report-generator#comment125256878_70852375), I think the way the documentation suggests the report gen functions are imported is bad practice. By using `import mlreportgen.dom.*` you are putting all of the nicely name-spaced functions from that package into the common area, and in this case it has caused an unclear clash between two things. So there are two options:

1. Use the namespaced version of `Height` (and `Width`), if you did this with all of the report gen functions you would not need the `import`. The nice side-effect is you get tab-completion when typing the various functions from this package

   ```
   lot.entry(1,1).Style = {mlreportgen.dom.Width('3.2in'), mlreportgen.dom.Height('3in')};
   ```

   Sure, you code is longer, but it is more explicit.

   **... or ...**
2. Simply don't define a variable called `Height`. Rename this and everything else can stay the same.